# Three row fluid scrolling center CSS layout

Tags: html, css

I am currently building the HTML and CSS for an application I am developing.

This application has a fixed height header, a fixed height footer and a middle area that should take up the rest of the space.

The problem is that I want the header and the footer to stay fixed in place the entire time, while the content scrolls if it becomes too big.

I've been able to get the content scrollable with the header and footer fixed in place, but this uses a push div which makes it so the scrollbar disappears behind the header, another option makes it disappear behind the footer.. I am having a hard time getting a div to scroll when it exceeds the max size without giving it a 100% height.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/7gmpu/

Is this possible with pure CSS? Or do I have to calculate the window height with javascript every time it resizes?

Is my 'solution' even close?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to have your elements fixed, you have to use CSS positioning. Your current solution is already close, however it's a little bit complicated.

Say you want to have three blocks:

```
HEADER
CONTENT
FOOTER
```

the most natural way is to put them all in a container (not needed if your website consists of only these 3 elements) and position them absolute. For HEADER top is 0, for FOOTER bottom is 0. In CONTENT you have to adjust top and bottom to ensure that it will be the height of your footer/header.

So if your using a #wrapper, #header, #content and #footer, this is the code you'll need:

```
#wrapper{position:absolute; top:0;bottom:0;width:100%;}
#header, #footer, #content{position:absolute; width:100%;}
#header{top:0; background-color:#faa;height:50px;}
#content{top:50px;bottom:150px; overflow:auto;}
#footer{bottom:0px; background-color:#afa; height:150px}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6K9w6/)

**EDIT**: [Your updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gmpu/1/). Don't specify a height value if you want to use fixed positioning. Use an implicit height instead by defining `top` and `bottom`. Also use `overflow:auto` for scrollbars. I did the following changes:

```
#mid {
    background:    #222;
    /* dropped height */
    bottom:50px; /* implicit height */
    overflow:auto; /* automatical scrollbars */
    width:        100%;    
    position:    fixed;
    top:        100px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think that just by setting top and bottom that the div would stretch. This is perfect!

Comment: You're welcome. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-non-replaced-height for more details.

Comment: @zeta This is an incredible example, thank you. What if one would want a 10px margin around the whole thing? I'm trying to a accomplish this but it seems to break everything. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tom: Woah, wait. This answer is 10 months old. Probably use `#wrapper{position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; left:10px; bottom:10px;}` and don't use `width` in `#wrapper`, since it gets calculated automatically. (It breaks in your code since the calculated width is more than 100%).

Comment: @Zeta Yeah sorry, I just came across this and it's exactly what I need. http://jsfiddle.net/7gmpu/26/ This doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect using very little markup. Given a HTMl that looks like

```
 <header>
     Header
 </header>
 <div id="container">
     <article class="post">
         A1;
     </article>
     <article class="post">
         A2;
     </article>
     <article class="post">
         A3;
     </article>
     <article class="post">
         A4;
     </article>
     <article class="post">
         A5;
     </article>
 </div>
 <footer>
     footer
 </footer>?
```

you can style it with the following css:

```
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 html, body {
     height: 100%;
 }

 body {
     padding-bottom: 5em;
     padding-top: 7em;
     position: relative;
 }

 body > div#container {
     position:absolute;
     top: 7em;
     bottom: 5em;
     width: 100%;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     min-height: 3em;

 }

 body > header {
     height:7em;
     position:relative;
     margin-top: -7em;
 }

 body > footer{
     height:5em;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
 }
```

and you should be ready to go. You can see a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/Mg4Ad/

In the code above the `header` is `7em`, the `footer` `5em` and the `#container` area shrinks down to `3 em`;